# react-google-maps OverlayMapType support

Tags: google-maps, reactjs, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to implement an ImageMapType as an overlay using [react-google-maps](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps). This works fine on vanilla Google Maps as per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#OverlayMapTypes).

However with this library, there is no `overlayMapTypes` array in the returned `map` object. Below is a code snippet adapted from the demo website:

```js
handleMapLoad(map) {
    this._map = map;
    this._navOverlay = new google.maps.ImageMapType(NAV_OVERLAY_OPTIONS);
    this._map.overlayMapTypes.push(this._navOverlay);
 }
// throws error 'Cannot read property 'push' of undefined'
```

I did find an `overlayMapTypes` array inside `map.context.__SECRET_MAP_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED` but I have a feeling I shouldn't be using that.

So how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If it is not there, then you can

a) Use the private values as a temporary solution

b) Develop an expansion of the library and make a pull request there. This is very similar to a, but when you are developing "inside" the library, now you have proper access.